# javascript, ajax, PHP insert onSubmit not working...POST not set

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to insert into my MySQL database with an onSubmit() function... For the main part, my function works. However, it keeps inserting a `1` into my DB where the `logbook_id` field is (the `logbook_id` should NOT be a 1 every time). Here's my (relevant) html:

```
echo '<div class="logbook_box" id="logbook'.$id.'" 
      style="display: block; overflow: hidden;">';
echo '<form action="cgi-bin/read_log.php" method="post"
      onSubmit="return ajaxSubmit(this, ' . $id . ');">' . 

'<input type="hidden" value="'.$id.'" id="id" name="id" />'.
'<input style="float: right; width: 20%" type="submit" value="Mark as Read" />' .
'</form>';
```

Here's the onSubmit function:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cgi-bin/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
<script>
var ajaxSubmit = function(form, id) {
    div = document.getElementById("logbook" + id);
    div.style.display = "none";
        // fetch where we want to submit the form to
        var url = $(form).attr('action');

        var id = $('#id').val();

    // setup the ajax request
    $.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: { id : id },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function() {
        if(rsp.success) {
            alert('Marked as read, thanks!');
            }
    }
    });

     // return false so the form does not actually
     // submit to the page
     return false;
}
</script>
```

And here's my PHP file:

```
<?php

include('/var/www/olin2/includes/functions.php');
$con = connect_db();
session_start();

$id = isset($_POST['id']);
$username = $_SESSION['username'];

$query = 'insert into read_logbook(logbook_id, username) 
          values("'.$id.'",     "'.$username.'")';
mysqli_query($con, $query) or die(mysqli_error($con));


?>
```

So, the `<div>` disappears like it should when Submit is clicked, which shows that the `id` is getting passed correctly. The PHP script is called, but it either doesn't input *anything* into the database, or (even more strangely) it will submit my username and the value `1` into the database *if* I change the PHP from `$_POST` to `$_GET` *without* changing the method in the form.

I'm new at ajax/javascript, so I'm sure it has something to do with the function, but I'm confused and at a complete loss... Any ideas?

Comment: `$id = isset($_POST['id']);` returns true or false not the post id…

Comment: What do you see when doing `div = document.getElementById("logbook" + id);` And when you say `<div> disappears like it should when Submit is clicked, which shows that the id is getting passed correctly` so even if the div is populated with any value(say everytime 1), it will disappear

Comment: @Class - I'm beating myself up pretty bad right now... you are correct, and have solved my issue. Add it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @Abu - Thank you, though my problem is solved I appreciate it. FYI - I've poured over the generated HTML and the div id's are set appropriately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add `type` option as `post` to your ajax since you are retriving the value as `post`...default is `get`..

```
 $.ajax({
  url: url,
  data: { id : id },
  type: "POST", //<---here
  ....
```

and make sure the id of logbook_box is different and not 1 all the time

and change this

```
$id = isset($_POST['id']);   //this return either true or false. so your $id is either 0 or 1
```

try this

```
$id = isset($_POST['id'])?$_POST['id']:""; //or $_POST['id'];
```

Comment: Thank you; I've added the `type: "POST",` as you've suggested, but I'm still getting a value of `1` in the `logbook_id` field of my DB... everything else works splendidly.

Comment: I saw that... hang on a few, new user with a wait time here!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
include('/var/www/olin2/includes/functions.php');
$con = connect_db();
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['id'])){
$id = $_POST['id'];
$username = $_SESSION['username'];

$query = 'insert into read_logbook(logbook_id, username) 
          values("'.$id.'",     "'.$username.'")';
mysqli_query($con, $query) or die(mysqli_error($con));
}
```

Comment: Thank you... after I was made aware of my mistake with `isset`, I actually changed the code to reflect what you've written.

Comment: gud luck to your project.